# Acro JS : hostContainer.postMessage is not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, acrobat

I am trying to send a message from a html page to an embedded PDF by using hostContainer.postMessage API from Acrobat Javascript API.
This works in IE9 but it does not work in Chrome and Firefox.
I have tried by disabling their own PDF viewer and enabling acrobat reader and still it does not work.

Does anyone face this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hostContainer.postMessage posts from active script (running in adobe reader activeX) to the the javascript running in browser. you saying you want it the other way around...

however if you want to post from within the active script running in pdf reader activex to the javascript runing in browser here's two sources that could help you

[Get the current page in PDF Java Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426288/get-the-current-page-in-pdf-java-web)
[pdf object.messagehandler onMessage not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871623/pdf-object-messagehandler-onmessage-not-working-in-ie/26803677#26803677)

personally I manage to make it work in IE but not in Chrome nor in FF.