# How to "postMessage" to host from within pdf when viewed in IE9 object element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf, internet-explorer-9, itext

I am attempting to do a small PoC with PDFs and have run into an issue.  I am looking to post a message to a PDF and have the PDF post a message to the browser.

**The deets:**

I am viewing the PDF in an "object" element in IE9.  I am using itextsharp to prefill a pdf template on the server, inject some app level javascript (post message and on message stuff) and then serve that up to the browser via a filestreamresult.  I am using Reader 10 to view the PDF in IE9.

**What works:**

So far, everything works except for the PDF posting a message to the browser.  I can post a message to the PDF, from the browser, no problem and all of the fields are prefilled as desired.

**What doesn't work:**

When I try using this.hostContainer.postMessage(["something","somethingmore"]) I get an Acrobat Escript window that says "hostContainer is not defined".  I have also tried using "event.target.hostContainer" but I get "event.target is not defined".  I am at a loss of what to do and any insight would be super helpful.

**Reference links:**

1. [Acrobat Javascript API](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)
2. [Stackoverflow How-To on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934211/getting-notified-when-the-user-clicks-a-link-in-an-embedded-pdf)
3. [Original guide I used](http://www.javabeat.net/javascript-communication-between-html-and-pdf-in-itext/)

**The code:**

*My form view:*

```
<object id="pdfFrame" style="width:100%;height: 100%;" data="@Url.Action("LoadForm")">No luck :(</object>
```

*My custom javascript string method:*

```
private static string GetCustomJavascript(string existingJavaScript)
    {
        const string newJs = 
        "this.disclosed = true; " +
        "if (this.external && this.hostContainer) { " +
            "function onMessageFunc( stringArray ) { " +
//                    "var name = this.myDoc.getField(personal.name); " +
//                    "var login = this.myDoc.getField(personal.loginname); " +
                    "try{" +
                        "app.alert(doc.xfa);" +
                        "console.println('Doc xfa value = ' + doc.xfa);" +
//                            "event.target.hostContainer.postMessage(['hello from pdf!']);" +
//                        "this.hostContainer.postMessage(['hello from pdf!']);"+
//                        "name.value = stringArray[0]; " +
//                        "login.value = stringArray[1]; " +
                    "} catch(e){ onErrorFunc(e); } " +
                "} " +
                "function onErrorFunc( e ) { " +
                    "console.show(); " +
                    "console.println(e.toString()); " +
                "} " +
                "try {" +
                    "if(!this.hostContainer.messageHandler) { " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler = new Object(); " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.myDoc = this; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onMessage = onMessageFunc; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onError = onErrorFunc; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onDisclose = function(){ return true; }; " +
                    "}" +
                "} catch(e){onErrorFunc(e);}" +
            "}";
            var jsToReturn = existingJavaScript + newJs;
            return jsToReturn;
        }
```

*My method for filling and sending the form to the browser:*

```
public MemoryStream GetFilledRequestForm(string fileDirectory, User user, FormView formView)
        {
            var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
            var templateFilePath = GetRequestTypeTemplateFilePath(fileDirectory, _requestModule.FormTemplateFileName);
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(templateFilePath);
//            pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfStream);
            var formFields = GetFormFields(user, formView, pdfReader);
            foreach (var field in formFields.Where(f => f.Value != null))
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetField(field.Name, field.Value);
            }
            stamper.FormFlattening = false;
            var newJs =  GetCustomJavascript(stamper.Reader.JavaScript);
            stamper.AddJavaScript("newJs", newJs);
            stamper.Close();
            byte[] byteInfo = pdfStream.ToArray();
            var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            outputStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            return outputStream;
        }
```

Comment: You might have seen this already but some people are talking the document mode and using the legacy class id attribute, maybe give that a shot. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1188852?tstart=0

Comment: I actually am just running into this.  How does one determine what the classid value should be?

Comment: The class id is what is listed in that thread, `clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000`. You can actually find that GUID by looking in the Windows registry under `HKCR\AcroPDF.PDF\CLSID`. That GUID is common across all computers that have Acrobat Reader installed.

Comment: Ok, yes, perfect, thank you.  I added that into my object element which now looks like this: <object classid="CLSID:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" id="pdfFrame" style="width:100%;height: 100%;" data="@Url.Action("LoadForm")">No luck :(</object>  but still it doesn't not work.

Comment: I have finally gotten it to work, I'm going to clean up my code and post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have resolved it, with some help of course.  I found the key at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871623/pdf-object-messagehandler-onmessage-not-working-in-ie/26803677#26803677).  I needed to wait for the object to load before assigning the message handler.  Additionally, I needed a global variable in the pdf javascript to be able to post the message.

Html/Javascript: (the key here is the loadListener() function)

```
    @model WebModel.FormView
<object id="pdfFrame" style="width:100%;height: 100%;" data="@Url.Action("LoadForm")">No luck :(</object>
    <input id="buttonPost" type="button" value="post to pdf"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var PDFObject = document.getElementById("pdfFrame");
        function loadListener() {
            if (typeof PDFObject.readyState === 'undefined') { // ready state only works for IE, which is good because we only need to do this for IE because IE sucks in the first place
                debugger;
                PDFObject.messageHandler = { onMessage: messageFunc };
                return;
            }
            if (PDFObject.readyState == 4) {
                debugger;
                PDFObject.messageHandler = { onMessage: messageFunc };
            } else {
                setTimeout(loadListener, 500);
            }
        }
        function messageFunc(data) {
            debugger;
            var messagedata = data;
            alert('finally!!');
        }

        function sendToPdf() {
            if(PDFObject!= null){
                PDFObject.postMessage(
                ["a", "b"]);
            }
        }

        $('#pdfFrame').ready(function() {
            loadListener();
            $('#buttonPost').on('click', function() {
                sendToPdf();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

My new function to create the javascript: (the key here is var appHostContainer)

```
private static string GetCustomJavascript(string existingJavaScript)
        {
            const string newJs = 
            "this.disclosed = true; " +
            "var appHostContainer = this.hostContainer;" + 
            "if (this.external && this.hostContainer) { " +
                "function onMessageFunc( stringArray ) { " +
//                    "var name = this.myDoc.getField(personal.name); " +
//                    "var login = this.myDoc.getField(personal.loginname); " +
                    "try{" +
                        "app.alert(stringArray);" +
                        "appHostContainer.postMessage(['hello from pdf!']);" +
//                        "name.value = stringArray[0]; " +
//                        "login.value = stringArray[1]; " +
                    "} catch(e){ onErrorFunc(e); } " +
                "} " +
                "function onErrorFunc( e ) { " +
                    "console.show(); " +
                    "console.println(e.toString()); " +
                "} " +
                "try {" +
                    "if(!this.hostContainer.messageHandler) { " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler = new Object(); " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.myDoc = this; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onMessage = onMessageFunc; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onError = onErrorFunc; " +
                        "this.hostContainer.messageHandler.onDisclose = function(){ return true; }; " +
                    "}" +
                "} catch(e){onErrorFunc(e);}" +
            "}";
            var jsToReturn = existingJavaScript + newJs;
            return jsToReturn;
        }
```

Comment: The code seems to have a problem: I have to change "PDFObject.messageHandler = { onMessage: messageFunc };" to "PDFObject.messageHandler = { onMessage: messageFunc() };" otherwise it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure why that would work.  Your code would execute the messageFunc() and set the result to "onMessage" property... that is strange.  Are there any hidden syntax errors?

Comment: @JasonWolczak: I agree to you. I think it "works", because it doesn't use the messageHandler mechanism. My loadListener function is called every 500 milliseconds and if I reach ready state it calls messageFunc() directly.   The printer.messageHandler = {onMessage:...} can be dropped in my case. I've to check how to get it work correctly.